# Вызов callback функции без дополнительного описания стрелочной функции в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, express, callback, modbus

Есть router на express:

```
import Router from "express";
import ModbusController from "../Controllers/ModbusController.js";

const mb = new ModbusController();

const modbusRouter = new Router();

modbusRouter.get('/write/:id/:action', (req, res) => mb.writeSingleCoil(req, res));
modbusRouter.get('/read/:id', (req, res) => mb.readSingleCoil(req, res));
modbusRouter.get('/read', (req, res) => mb.readAllCoils(req, res));

export default modbusRouter;
```

Есть класс ModbusController:

```
import modbus from "jsmodbus";
import net from "net";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

export default class ModbusController {
// много неважного кода
  readSingleCoil(req, res) {
    const {id} = req.params
    this.client.readCoils(id,1)
      .then( resp => {
        const coilStatus = resp.response._body._valuesAsArray[0];
        res.status(200).json({ch: id, status: coilStatus})
      })
      .catch(e => this.errorOccurred(e))
  }
```

Так все работает, но я почти на 100% уверен, что строчку вызова функции из контроллера можно записать так:

```
modbusRouter.get('/read/:id', mb.readSingleCoil);
```

Почему у меня выскакивает ошибка: '(node:11488) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'readSingleCoil' of undefined'  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что, когда Вы делаете

```
modbusRouter.get('/read/:id', mb.readSingleCoil);
```

Вы передаете в `get` функцию без контекста.

---

Если очень хочется избавиться от анонимной функции во втором параметре:

```
modbusRouter.get('/read/:id', mb.readSingleCoil.bind(mb));
```

Comment: отличный развёрнутый ответ!

Comment: Но ведь если сделать такую функцию: test(req, res) { return res.status(200).json('OK') } то вызов modbusRouter.get('/test', mb.test); нормально работает. Там что-то с async await нужно сделать

Comment: @merlinby "то вызов ... нормально работает" - ключевое слово - "контекст". В `test` Вы нигде не обращаетесь к `this`.

Comment: @igor вроде начинает понемногу доходить. Почитал ветку, которую повесили на "дубликат". Т.е. правильно я понял, что в моем случае нужно просто оставить код как есть и не дурить головы?

Comment: @merlinby Да, оставить.

Comment: @merlinby `modbusRouter.get('/read/:id', mb.readSingleCoil.bind(mb));`

Comment: @igor Спасибо огромное! Думаю можно написать в основном Вашем ответе, может кому понадобиться такая конструкция.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin наконец-то у Александра эйфория, катарсис от ответов Игоря :D